# Excel VBA - Replace a text inside cell's formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have faced a strange thing in Excel VBA coding.

I have a sheet full of formulas, each refers to the cells in other sheets.

This is a sample formula in cell A1, for example:

```
=IF('General Inputs & Summary'!B6="","",'General Inputs & Summary'!B6)
```

I want to dynamically change the old tab names in formulas, with new tab names.

When I try this code:

```
oldStr = "'General Inputs & Summary'"
newStr = "'test'"  
Range("A1").Formula = Replace(Range("A1").Formula, oldStr, newStr)
```

it results in:

```
=IF(test!B6="","",test!B6)
```

instead of:

```
=IF('test'!B6="","",'test'!B6)
```

You see, single Quotes are automatically removed, so the new formula fails!

Any solutions for this, please?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. In your example the removal of the quotes is actually correct, since you only need quotes if the sheet-name contains a space.

Comment: The quotes are automatically removed because `test` does not contain any spaces and quotes are only needed when there are spaces in your worksheet name. Your formula might fail because of other reasons but not because of the quotes here. Can you be more specific what "*fails*" mean? What error does it show? Is there a sheet called `test`? Is calculation turned to `xlAutomatic`? If not run calculate after changing the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to read the formula to a string, replace in the string and pass the string as a new formula like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim oldStr$, newStr$

    oldStr = "'General Inputs & Summary'"
    newStr = "'test'"
    newStr = Replace(Range("A1").Formula, oldStr, newStr)
    Range("A1").Formula = newStr

End Sub
```

---

To illustrate the `'` take a look at this example:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim a As Range
    Dim b As String
    Set a = Range("A1")

    b = "'12"
    a = b

    Debug.Print a 'prints 12
    Debug.Print b 'prints '12

End Sub
```

The cell in `A1` is formatted as text and contains the `'`, but the printed value is without it.

---

**Edit:**
In general, the `'` is needed only when the worksheet name contains spaces, like this one - `General Inputs & Summary`. Without spaces in the name, like `test`, it is not quite needed, thus this example works as well:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim a As Range: Set a = Range("A1")
    Dim oldStr$, newStr$

    a.Formula = "=IF('GI S'!B6="","",'GI S'!B6)"

    oldStr = "'GI S'"
    newStr = "'test'"
    Range("A1").Formula = Replace(Range("A1").Formula, oldStr, newStr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Just for my interest: Can you explain how replacing into a variable `newStr = Replace` is different from `.Formula = Replace(` and why this should help? I mean the first parameter of replace is a `String` so you with `Replace(Range("A1").Formula, ` you cast that formula into a string already so you actually are replacing in a string not in a cell or a formula. And then write that string that is returned from replace into a formula of a cell. I cannot see any difference in using a variable as intermediate step.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - thank you for your interest - I have updated the example.

Comment: Well, of course I know this fact in your Example. But I wonder how this relates to the OPs question? The `'` is never in first place in the OPs formula but inside an `IF` statement. And replacing dosn't change that fact. And the original string `'General Inputs & Summary'` contains also a `'` so after a replace the `'` are still in the same place as before, just something in between them changed. Maybe I'm just blind but I cannot see any solution by using your code instead of the OPs code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - the code of the OP does not work. The code I wrote works. The reason is that `.Formula` and `Replace` tend to ignore the special sign `'`.

Comment: Well the OPs code works exactly as yours. I tested it. The `'` are just omitted due to the fact that the sheetname `test` dosen't contain a space and therefore the quotes are not needed. Both codes are working. No difference. And replace doesn't ignore any `'` at all. Even if you type `='test'!A1` by hand it will remove the quotes

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - strange. I have tried the OP code, it did not work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168096/discussion-between-p-and-vityata).

Comment: I just realized 'test'!A1 is indeed equal to test!A1, so this was not the reason I was getting #REF! and I explain the reason in reply...thx

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Vityata for your nice explanations, which led me to the answer!

The problem is, the macro was "First" replacing the name in formulas (i.e to test) and THEN creating the new tab "test".

For example, if you set this formula in `sheet1`, cell A1:

```
=test2!A1
```

(Note that you have not created the `test2` sheet, yet)

So you obviously get `#REF!` error.

However, if you THEN create `test2` tab (by macro or hand), and come back and check cell A1 formula in `sheet1`, (also refresh by saving the file), it STILL shows `#REF!` error, even now `test2` tab is really there! (You need to Double click on the cell, and press enter, for that to UPDATE)

As a result, I changed my macro so that it FIRST creates the `test` tab, and THEN manipulate those formulas.