# Find and Replace VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am trying to use a dynamic drop down table which adjusts the formulas in a sheets. (for example if the drop down value is abc, then part of the formulas will be adjusted via find and replaced)
If I do it manually, it works out perfectly, but the code just selects my range and doesn't do anything else. I recorded my manual work with the Macro recorder and get the following result:

```
Sub a()
Range("B50:I60","B30:I40","B70:I90").Select
Selection.Replace What:=")", Replacement:=";Sheet1!X:X;"";9;"")", _ LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ ReplaceFormat:=Format, FOrmulaBersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    Sub replace()
    If Range("A2").Value="Juli 2020" _
    Then Range("B50:I60","B30:I40","B70:I90").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=")", Replacement:=";Sheet1!X:X;"";9;"")", _ LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ ReplaceFormat:=Format, FOrmulaBersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    End If
End Sub
```

Both of these codes don't work when I run them from VBA, event though if I do it manually I can easily adjust my formulas.
PS:I thought refering to the worksheet directly and activate it would help but it doesn't change anything.
Can anyone help? It's very frustrating…
Hugs,
Annabelle

Comment: `Select` and `Activate` are usually unnecessary and frequently cause problems. Fully qualify your references in your code.  Use a break point to see which worksheet and workbook your ranges are referring to. Also read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: There are several issues with this code, both those pointed out above and the fact that the last two parameters (`ReplaceFormat:=Format, FOrmulaBersion:=xlReplaceFormula2`) are invalid. It is customary to provide code examples that actually compile, so please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Anyway, you probably want to take a somewhat different approach to the problem as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623964/excel-vba-replace-a-text-inside-cells-formula

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: I simple was wrong **not being sure**... I will delete my comment.

Comment: `Range("B50:I60,B30:I40,B70:I90")`

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your comments. My main problem is that the recorded code is not working when I try to run it. That never happened to me before.. Right now I tried a very simple code which should work, but doesn't. Am I seeing something the wrong way? Thanks again for your help.
`Sub Makro1()
    Range("A5:D21").Replace What:=")", Replacement:=";Table1!M:M;""c"")", LookAt:=xlPart
End Sub`

Comment: It works just fine if I replace a word by another one (text format), but not when I am looking to replace values in formulas..

Comment: I found the answer: I need to define the find and replace objects as strings: `Sub Replace_Example()
 Dim Replacetext As String
Dim Findtext As String
If Range("A1").Value = "a" Then
    Findtext = ")"
    Replacetext = ",Tabelle1!M:M,""a"")"
    Range("A5:D20").replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False End if End Sub`