# Excel VBA Array Formula using Index Match giving an error Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas, type-mismatch

I'm trying to add an Array formula into a Table column on a worksheet. I'm using Index Match and splitting the formula because it gets quite big with all the file names. I use it in other parts of the code by splitting it and it works (but using different references, etc).

I keep getting an error "Type mismatch" when I try and replace/insert the Match formula into the Index formula. When I do it manually (by copying the variable string values) it works...

```
ATPFile = Dir(DataPath & "\*ATP*COMBINED.xls*")
ATPFileF = DataPath & "\" & ATPFile

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ATPFileF)

'Add ATP data from ATP raw data file
sheetname = Worksheets("ATP").Name

'Get last row with data in ATP file
Dim rowCountSource As Integer
Dim ATPRowRange As Range
Dim sFomrula2 As String

With wb.Worksheets("ATP")
    rowCountSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
End With

ref = DataPath & "\[" & ATPFile & "]" & sheetname

sFormula = "=INDEX('" & ref & "'!$P$1:$P$" & rowCountSource & ",""X_X_X"",1)"
sFormula2 = "MATCH([@Article]&[@Site],('" & ref & "'!$B$1:$B$" & rowCountSource & ")&('" & ref & "'!$D$1:$D$" & rowCountSource & "),0)"

'Add ATP info
With ws.ListObjects("Table_DCvenSDCdata")
    With .ListColumns("ATP").DataBodyRange
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .FormulaArray = sFormula
            .Replace """X_X_X""", sFormula2
        End With
        .FillDown
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

The error pops up at `.Replace """X_X_X""", sFormula2`

The file references and names are all correct. I'm not sure where in my match formula the issue is...

This is what the sFormula string is:

```
=INDEX('C:\_Store\10.05.2020\[T MA0 ATP 18.08.2020.xls COMBINED.xls]ATP'!$P$1:$P$126,"X_X_X",1)
```

And This is what the sFormula2 string is that replaces the "X_X_X" in the Index formula:

```
MATCH([@Article]&[@Site],('C:\_Store\10.05.2020\[T MA0 ATP 18.08.2020.xls COMBINED.xls]ATP'!$B$1:$B$126)&('C:\_Store\10.05.2020\[T MA0 ATP 18.08.2020.xls COMBINED.xls]ATP'!$D$1:$D$126),0)
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the formula must resolve at every step.  replace the `""X_X_X""` with `0`, then replace that instead.

Comment: Then look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another and see if you can redo your formula not to be an array formula.

Comment: `Cells(1.1).Replace` would replace contents in value of Cells(1,1), it wont edit formula the way you are doing here. Try putting line of `sFormula2` before that of `sFormula` & then in place of `sFormula = "=INDEX('" & ref & "'!$P$1:$P$" & rowCountSource & ",""X_X_X"",1)"` try `sFormula = "=INDEX('" & ref & "'!$P$1:$P$" & rowCountSource & ", sFormula2 ,1)"`

Comment: After that remove or comment out `.Replace """X_X_X""", sFormula2` from `with block`.

Comment: @Puntal the problem is that `.FormulaArray` has a 255 character limit and as a work around it must be done in multiple steps to enter one that is longer.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried replacing the `""X_X_X""` with `0` and replacing it, as you suggested. Unfortunately, that didn't work. It still gives the same error of type mismatch. I've looked at the link you suggested and the Index Match formula is my best option but that links suggested formula will get very very long! I'm guessing then my formula is giving the error because of the 255 limit, even though it was split for that reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question with the solution I came up with. I'm sure there are other ways, but this was the quickest easiest way that worked for me. I split my formula even further since the 255 character limit seemed to be the problem, as @Scott Craner mentioned.

The part of the code that changed now looks like this:

```
sFormula = "=INDEX('" & ref & "'!$P$1:$P$" & rowCountSource & ",""X_X_X"",1)"
sFormula2 = "MATCH([@Article]&[@Site],""X3""&""X4"",0)"
sFormula3 = "('" & ref & "'!$B$1:$B$" & rowCountSource & ")"
sFormula4 = "('" & ref & "'!$D$1:$D$" & rowCountSource & ")"

'Add ATP info
With ws.ListObjects("Table_DCvenSDCdata")
    With .ListColumns("ATP").DataBodyRange
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .FormulaArray = sFormula
            .Replace """X_X_X""", sFormula2
            .Replace """X3""", sFormula3
            .Replace """X4""", sFormula4
        End With
        .FillDown
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet of `With` block along with some declarations just before it as mentioned.

```
Dim oldStr As String, newStr As String

    oldStr = """X_X_X"""
    newStr = "sFormula2"

With ws.ListObjects("Table_DCvenSDCdata")
    With .ListColumns("ATP").DataBodyRange
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .FormulaArray = sFormula
            .FormulaArray = Replace(.FormulaArray, oldStr, newStr)
        End With
        .FillDown
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623964/excel-vba-replace-a-text-inside-cells-formula) relevant link.

Comment: Hi @Puntal I tried this code, which didn't work, unfortunately. It just adds `"sFormula2"` into the Index formula. I tried removing the `""` like so `newStr = sFormula2` to see what it does. I then get an error **Unable to set FormulaArray property of the range class**. I did follow the link you suggested but it's basically the same as your formula, so still not working for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @SimoneFick .. Good that you got the solution. I had simulated your requirement as per your question & tried running the code which worked at my end. Anyways, other option could have been is using `Function sFormula2(x,z,z) as Integer` wherein `x`, `y`, & `z` are values you pass into Function to return value of `sFormula2`. This will help you to directly pass evaluated value of `sFormula2` into Formula of `sFormula`.