# Create a new worksheet from a template and link the new worksheet to a master log

Tags: excel, vba

Template sheet labeled = "COQ 001"
Log labeled = "Change Order Log"

I have gotten this far: Code below creates a new sheet based off of the template labeled "COQ 001", renames the new worksheet based on user input, goes back to the change order log and sets it to active, inserts a row after the last entry. I think I got that right.

```vb
    Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim xName As String
    Dim xSht As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    xName = InputBox("Please enter new COQ #. For Example: COQ 001", "NEW CHANGE ORDER QUOTE")
    If xName = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xSht = Sheets(xName)
    If Not xSht Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Sheet cannot be created as there is already a worksheet with the same name in this 
    workbook"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Sheets("COQ 001").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set xNWS = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    xNWS.Name = xName
    'Link2Log Macro
    Worksheets("Change Order Log").Activate
    'Locates Last Cell
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Inserts Row Below
     Range("10:10").EntireRow.Insert
    End Sub
```

To keep going I need it to link specific cells of each newly created worksheet to the change order log sheet since that is my master log. Instead of COQ 001 which shows up on the formula, I would like it to be each newly created sheet.

[image]

If anyone can help finish the thought that would be great!!Thanks,

New Formula:
Thanks Nick, this is what the formula looks like:

```
Sub CreateSheet()
Dim xName As String
Dim xSht As Object
On Error Resume Next
xName = InputBox("Please enter new COQ #. For Example: COQ 001", "NEW 
CHANGE ORDER QUOTE")
If xName = "" Then Exit Sub
Set xSht = Sheets(xName)
If Not xSht Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Sheet cannot be created as there is already a worksheet with 
the same name in this workbook"
Exit Sub
End If
Sheets("COQ 001").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set xNWS = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
xNWS.Name = xName
'Link2Log Macro
Worksheets("Change Order Log").Activate
Range("10:10").EntireRow.Insert
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='xName'!R[-3]C[5]"
Range("C10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='xName'!R[2]C:R[2]C[5]"
Range("D10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='xName'!R[-2]C[3]"
Range("E10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='xName'!R[-1]C[2]"
Range("G10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='xName'!R[40]C"
Range("G11").Select
End Sub
```

But I get an error on the log:
[LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYrCh.png)

Comment: You can to replace the text of all the formulae in your new Sheet from 'COQ 001' to xName (the name of the new Sheet)
Take a look at the following topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623964/excel-vba-replace-a-text-inside-cells-formula

Comment: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & xName & "'!R[-3]C[5]"` etc

Comment: Awesome! That worked great. The only thing is, how do I get the newly inserted row to show up under the last entry? That way can follow down the log in numerical order.. 1,2,3 etc..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```vb
Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim xName As String, wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    xName = InputBox("Please enter new COQ #. For Example: COQ 001", _
                      "NEWCHANGE ORDER QUOTE")
    If xName = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    If SheetExists(xName, wb) Then
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & xName & "' cannot be created as there is already " & _
               "a worksheet with the same name in this workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    wb.Worksheets("COQ 001").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ws.Name = xName
    
    With wb.Worksheets("Change Order Log")
        .Activate
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert 'add a row to the table
        With .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
            .Columns("B").Formula = "='" & xName & "'!G7"
            .Columns("C").Formula = "='" & xName & "'!C12" 'only need first cell of merged area
            .Columns("D").Formula = "='" & xName & "'!G8"
            .Columns("E").Formula = "='" & xName & "'!G9"
            .Columns("G").Formula = "='" & xName & "'!G50" 'likewise
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook)
    Dim s As Excel.Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set s = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetExists = Not s Is Nothing
End Function
```

Note you don't need to select/activate ranges to work with them - just reference them directly.

Comment: See update above

Comment: Sorry, this one didn't work and doesn't populate anything on the log. The previous version works great, it just inputs on row B10 every time though. Can I keep as it was before, but just help with inserting it after the last row with data to keep the numerical sequence? Thanks,

Comment: One more update above - that should do it

Comment: That didn't populate anything either. Maybe it's just on my end?

Comment: Working OK for me...  Are you sure you don't have content somewhere in ColB below where you're expecting the links to show up?   I'm assuming there's nothing below the summary table...

Comment: after COQ 002 is generated, the fixed cells within each sheet that the macro grabs the data from is now incrementing by 1, for example: when it is ='COQ 002'!G7, for the next one I am getting ='COQ 003'!G8 etc. It is doing that for all new sheets past COQ 002 on all the cells on the log...

Comment: Because you're using R1C1 notation in your formulas instead of A1 notation.  If you want a fixed location then use (eg) `.Columns("B").Formula = "='" & xName & "'!D4"`  I hardly ever (never) use R1C1 so I missed that...

Comment: it's the same. Thanks for the help by the way! I don't have any data under the log that would make it act funny either. I removed the R1C1 notation like you said and it does the same thing after COQ 002 is generated.

Comment: I can take a look if you can share a workbook which reproduces the problem (preferably with no other code in it apart from the code in question)

Comment: Yes, thanks, How can I send it to you?

Comment: Updated code above based on your file